# customize fb-share button api function

Tags: javascript, facebook

http://www.fbshare.net/implementing-facebook-share/

i need to call a javascript function after share has been successfully completed
how can i implement this ?

does anybody know that which function in api is being used by fb-share button

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you want to do isn't possible.

The way Facebook Share is implemented means that it is effectively a data pulling mechanism with no interactive features.  Every time someone loads your web page with a FB Share widget on it, the widget queries Facebook to get the latest "count".  Essentially, whenever someone shares your page on Facebook, the URL is noted and a statistic counter for that URL is incremented.  The widget you are rendering simply asks for that current count.

You can use the API [Links.getStats](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.getStats/) callto get all of the information about a Share URL, but there is no scripting functionality available.

Comment: i need to grab title and url which fb-share button sending to facebook server after i shared content via fb-share is it possible ?